# Matlab: Multiplication and sum of products

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

How can I effeciently perform matrix multiplication for 10 pairs of arrays and sum the corresponding result of multiplication matrices? For example:

Create two arrays, A1 and B1.

```
A1 = [1 3 5; 2 4 7];
B1 = [-5 8 11; 3 9 21; 4 0 8];
```

Calculate the product of A1 and B1.

```
C1 = A1*B1

C1 =

    24    35   114
    30    52   162
```

Create another two arrays, A2 and B2.

```
A2 = [7 9 11; 3 5 6];
B2 = [-1 2 3; 4 5 6; 4 1 8];
```

Calculate the product of A2 and B2.

```
C2 = A2*B2



sum_of_products1 = sum(C1,C2);
sum_of_products2 = sum(C3,C4); and so on till 


    .
    .
    .
sum_of_products5 = sum(C9,C10);
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the reply, I input vectors. The result of summation is coming incorrect.

```
clc;
clear all;

%VECTORS
A1(:,1) = [1 2 3 4].';
A1(:,2) = [5 6 7 8].';

%// Concatenate all An and Bn arrays along third dim to have A, B as 3D arrays
A = cat(3,A1(:,1),A1(:,2));
B = cat(3,A1(:,1)',A1(:,2)');

%// You may clear A1, A2,...A10, B1, B2.., B10 at this point for a cleaner workspace

%// Get the product values into a 3D array
multvals = squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 2 4 3]),permute(B,[4 1 2 3])),2))

%// Finally get the sum of product values
sumvals = squeeze(sum(reshape(multvals,size(A,1),size(A,2),2,[]),3))
```

**Answer**

multvals(:,:,1) =

```
 1     2     3     4
 2     4     6     8
 3     6     9    12
 4     8    12    16
```

multvals(:,:,2) =

```
25    30    35    40
30    36    42    48
35    42    49    56
40    48    56    64
```

sumvals =

```
 3     7    55    75
 6    14    66    90
 9    21    77   105
12    28    88   120
```

**The correct answer should have been**

```
s1 = multvals(:,:,1);
s2 = multvals(:,:,2); 

sumvals = s1 + s2;

sumvals = 
26  32  38  44
32  40  48  56
38  48  58  68
44  56  68  80
```

Comment: At least for workspace efficiency, consider having a 3D array to contain all those 5 pairs of arrays. With your code and the intended outputs, you are already calling for 15 variables for a messy workspace.

Comment: @Divakar:I am not familiar working with 3D arrays. Could you please show how I can loop through the multiplication and sum? Thank you

Comment: Check out the posted solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through all those arrays, you can concatenate them into two 3D arrays and work with them.

```
%// Concatenate all An and Bn arrays along third dim to have A, B as 3D arrays
A = cat(3,A1,A2,...)
B = cat(3,B1,B2,...)

%// You may clear A1, A2,..., B1, B2..., at this point for a cleaner workspace

%// Get the product values into a 3D array
multvals = sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 2 4 3]),permute(B,[4 1 2 3])),2)

%// Finally get the sum of product values
[m1,m2,m3,m4] = size(multvals);
sumvals = squeeze(sum(reshape(multvals,m1,m2,m3,2,[]),4))
```

Each slice in the last dimension of `multvals` would correspond to each of those `C` arrays. At the end each `3D` slice of `sumvals` would correspond to each `sum_of_products` array.

---

### Samples runs with vectors and matrices

**1) Vector case**

```
clear all;clc;

%// VECTORS
A1 = [1 2 3 4].';
B1 = [5 6 7 8];

A2 = [11 12 13 14].';
B2 = [15 16 17 18];

A = cat(3,A1,A2);
B = cat(3,B1,B2);

multvals = sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 2 4 3]),permute(B,[4 1 2 3])),2);
[m1,m2,m3,m4] = size(multvals);
sumvals = squeeze(sum(reshape(multvals,m1,m2,m3,2,[]),4))

solution_with_approach_from_question = A1*B1 + A2*B2 
%// this should yield values identical to sumvals(:,:,1)
```

Output -

```
sumvals =
   170   182   194   206
   190   204   218   232
   210   226   242   258
   230   248   266   284
solution_with_approach_from_question =
   170   182   194   206
   190   204   218   232
   210   226   242   258
   230   248   266   284
```

**2) Matrix case**

```
clear all;clc;

%// MATRICES
A1 = [1 3 5; 2 4 7];
B1 = [-5 8 11; 3 9 21; 4 0 8];

A2 = [7 9 11; 3 5 6];
B2 = [-1 2 3; 4 5 6; 4 1 8];

A = cat(3,A1,A2);
B = cat(3,B1,B2);

multvals = sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1 2 4 3]),permute(B,[4 1 2 3])),2);
[m1,m2,m3,m4] = size(multvals);
sumvals = squeeze(sum(reshape(multvals,m1,m2,m3,2,[]),4))

solution_with_approach_from_question = A1*B1 + A2*B2 
%// this should yield values identical to sumvals(:,:,1)
```

Output -

```
sumvals =
    97   105   277
    71    89   249
solution_with_approach_from_question =
    97   105   277
    71    89   249
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Can you please explain what does the numbers in permute[1 2 4 3] and  others mean? Also, Will this same thing work for vectors as well for ex. where A1 = [1 2 3].' and B1 is [5 6 7]?

Comment: I checked the code when the input is a one dimensional vectors. The result of summation is coming incorrect. I have posted the result in my Question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @SrishtiM If you are looking to test out the code from the solution on a minimal level, look here and see if that makes sense - https://ideone.com/N3xGw4

Comment: @SrishtiM And I am sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to do in the Update section of the question. Originally, you had A1, A2,... B1, B2... arrays and my solution suggested to concatenate those arrays into a 3D array, whereas in the Update, you are concatenating the columns of A with `A = cat(3,A1(:,1),A1(:,2));`. Those two are entirely two different things. More importantly, originally you were multiplying `A1` and `B1` and so on. How are you doing that in the Update?

Comment: In the Question I had asked about matrix multiplication which worked according to your answer. I wanted to test the solution if it works for 1D array/vector. A1 is a single variable that stores different vectors as A1(:,1), A1(:,2) where 1, 2 index is used to store different vectors. I am trying to multiply [1 2 3 4].' with [5 6 7  8] to get a 4*4 matrix. How can I use your code so that it works for vectors and matrices?

Comment: @SrishtiM Guess it wasn't generic enough to handle vectors before. Thank you on asking for clarifications on those. Check out if the edits make sense now?

Comment: Thank you for your updates. Does the m1,m2,m3 hold any significance? I ask this because I tried multiplying 3 pairs of vectors with 4 elements and it throws error - Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 32, not divisible into total number of elements, 48.

Error in Untitled9 (line 18)
sumvals = squeeze(sum(reshape(multvals,m1,m2,m3,2,[]),4)). Can you look into this? Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @SrishtiM The code as it is now should work fine for three pairs or any number of pairs. Not sure how you are inputting values. Here's an example - https://ideone.com/8OjS8G Try with it?

Comment: Apologies, it was my mistake. Actually, I am adopting your answer in the code that I presented again in my Question. Could you help in mentioning how the cat function will work? What I am doing is, I am generating different time series of autoregressive  model of order 1 - AR(1) by varying the noise level. Then, I am taking data points from y(end-2:end-1).' and multiplying with its transpose. In this case, I am unsure how the cat function will work. Shall really appreciate your help and patience. Thank you.

Comment: @SrishtiM Well as the official [doc](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) states, `cat` just concatenates elements along the specified dimension. Since we know that we are dealing with 1D (vectors) and 2D (matrices) here, thus the third dimension is "vacant" and elements could be concatenated along that dimension. That's basically what's `cat ` is doing here. On the your time-series problem, I think that's out of the context here and would qualify as a separate question. Good luck!